# ASP.Net WebApi Two step authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

One step authentication is easy, by either using `Authorize` attribute or any custom authorize attribute. But can anyone suggest any way to implement a two step authentication in asp.net web API callable from a JavaScript client:

**1) First Step:**
*User & Password*

will do the partial authentication

**2) Second Step:**

***Memorable word***

complete authentication

After completing the authentication we can set the current pricipal to a valid user.

Comment: Have you checked: (1) http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity and (2) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingTwoFactorAuthenticationToAnASPNETApplication.aspx ?

Comment: Good starting point. Thanks.

Comment: I was interested in that as well, so I had those in my bookmarks. My company is thinking about introducing two-factor authentication for all internet-facing applications soon, so I was looking into that. I haven't done anything about it yet though, since they haven't enforced this yet, but they will...